# 4-momentum commutative with gamma matrix?

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I was checking the adjoint Dirac equation derivation.

Starting from:
\begin{equation}
(\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m) u = 0.
\end{equation}

We take the hermitian conjugate on both sides

\begin{equation}
0 = u^\dagger ((\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m))^\dagger.
\end{equation}

Since m is a scalar, $m^\dagger = m$
\begin{equation}
0 = u^\dagger ((p_\mu)^\dagger (\gamma^\mu)^\dagger  - m).
\end{equation}

And all entries of $p_\mu$ are real, so $p_\mu^\dagger = p_\mu$
\begin{equation}
0 = u^\dagger ((p_\mu) (\gamma^\mu)^\dagger  - m).
\end{equation}

We also know that $(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger = \gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$
\begin{equation}
0 = u^\dagger ((p_\mu) \gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0  - m).
\end{equation}

Now, I'm having a hard time understanding why one can jump to the next step:
\begin{equation}
0 = u^\dagger (\gamma^0 \not p \gamma^0  - m).
\end{equation}

Wouldn't that imply that $p_\mu$ can commute with the gamma's matrices? Does it has something to do with the fact that $p_\mu$ is a number (for every $\mu = \{0,1,2,3\}$)?

Comment: You got it, $p_\mu$ is just a scalar for a given $\mu$ so it commutes with all matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that $m$ isn't actually a scalar here, in the sense of just being a number, we are actually supressing spinor indices, indeed $m$ could more precisely be written as $$m\cdot \Bbb {I^\alpha}_{\beta}, \tag{1}$$ where $\Bbb {I^\alpha}_{\beta}$ is the identity on the spinor space of appropriate dimension and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the spinor indices (and in which $m$ really *is* a scalar, i.e. a real number). Apply the same reasoning to $p_\mu$ here and see if you can see how to resolve your issue.

Comment: What is the dot supposed to mean?

Comment: @Ghoster the dot is just really a multiplication